# Reverse for 'update' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['vehicles_app/(?P<post_id>[0-9]+)/update_post/$']

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have searched a lot, but couldn't find a solution. There are a lot of related questions being asked before and I think there's no mistake but there's still an error.

```
Reverse for 'update' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['vehicles_app/(?P<post_id>[0-9]+)/update_post/$']
```

Here is my `index.html`

```
{% for obj in context %}

<div class="container" style="padding-left:240px; padding-right:0px; width: 78%; margin-bottom:30px;">
    <div class="well" style=" background-color: rgb(220, 220, 220);">
        <div class="media">
            <div class="media-body">
          <div class="list-group">
              <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
            <h1 class="media-heading" style="margin-top:20px; margin-bottom:20px; color: black;">{{ obj.title }}</h1>
          {% for img in obj.postpicture_set.filter %}
            <div class="w3-content" style="max-width:800px">
                {% if img.image %}
                   <img style="margin-bottom:30px; float: right" class="mySlides" src="{{ img.image.url }}" width="200" height="180">
                {% endif %}
              </div>
          {% endfor %}
            <p> {{ obj.details }} </p>
            <ul class="list-inline list-unstyled">
                <li><span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i> {{ obj.date }} </span></li>
              <li>|</li>
              <span><i></i> {{ obj.brand }} </span>
                  <li>|</li>
                  <span><i></i> {{ obj.city }} </span><br>

              <form action="{% url 'vehicles_app:data' obj.id %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %} <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="{{ obj.id }}">
                <input type="hidden" name="usr_id" value="{{ obj.user_id }}">
                <td><input style="margin-top:70px; margin-bottom:20px; margin-left:10px;" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Details"</td></form>
                {% if request.user == obj.user or request.user.is_superuser %}

                <form action="{% url 'vehicles_app:file-delete' obj.id %}" method="post" style="display: inline;">{% csrf_token %} <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="{{ obj.id }}">
                  <td><input style="margin-top:70px; margin-bottom:20px; margin-left:10px;" type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"</td></form>


                  <form action="{% url 'vehicles_app:update' obj.id %}" method="post" style="display: inline;">{% csrf_token %}<input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="{{ obj.id }}">
                    <td><input style="margin-top:70px; margin-bottom:20px; margin-left:10px;" type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"</td></form>  
                    {% else %}
                    {% endif %}
                    </ul>
             </div>
        </div>
           </div>
         </div>

         </div>
         </div>
        {% endfor %}
```

Here is views.py

```
def update_post(request, post_id):
    ImageFormSet = modelformset_factory(
        PostPicture,
        form=AddPictures,
        extra=10,
        min_num=1
    )
    post_form = get_object_or_404(Posts, pk=post_id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AddFile(request.POST, instance=post_form)
        formset = ImageFormSet(
            queryset=PostPicture.objects.filter(
                post=post_id
            )
        )
        if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
            form.save()

            for form in formset:
                if form:
                    image = form['image']
                    photo = PostPicture(post=form, image=image)
                    photo.save()
                    messages.success(
                        request, 'Post submitted Successfully!'
                    )
                    return render(
                        request,
                        'vehicles_app/update_post.html',
                        {
                            'form': form,
                            'formset': formset, 
                            'post_form':post_form
                        }
                    )
        else:
            print(form.errors, formset.errors)
else:
    form = AddFile()
    formset = ImageFormSet(
        queryset=PostPicture.objects.none()
    )
    return render(
        request,
        'vehicles_app/update_post.html',
        {
            'form': form,
            'formset': formset,
            'post_form':post_form
        }
    )
```

Here is the url for my update, only update is not working, but other things like data and delete are working fine.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^signUp/$', views.signUp, name='signUp'),
    url(r'^user_login/$', views.user_login, name='user_login'),
    url(r'^addfile/$', views.addfile, name='addfile'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/delete/$', views.FileDelete.as_view(), name='file-delete'),
    url(r'^(?P<post_id>[0-9]+)/data/$', views.data, name='data'),
    url(r'^(?P<post_id>[0-9]+)/update_post/$', views.update_post, name='update'),
    url(r'^myposts/$', views.myposts, name='myposts'),
    url(r'^received/$', views.received, name='received'),
    url(r'^received_files/$', views.received_files, name='received_files'),
]
```

here is my update_post.html

```
    {% extends "vehicles_app/index.html" %}
    {% block body_block %}
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <html>
    <body>

              <div class="container" id="addfile_form" style="margin-                        left:200px; width: 78%;">
          <!-- <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-6 col-sm-offset-2 col-        md-offset-2"> -->
          <div class="panel panel-default">

            <div>
             {% if messages %}
               <ul class="messages">
                 {% for message in messages %}
                 <h2 style="margin-left:100px;">  {{ message }} </h2>
                 {% endfor %}
               </ul>
             {% endif %}
           </div>

        <div class="panel-heading">
          <b><h2 id="post_head" class="panel-title">Update Post here!</h2>                  
     </b>
        </div>
              <div class="panel-body">
            <form id="post_form" method="post" action="{% url 
    'vehicles_app:update_post' post_id %}"
                  enctype="multipart/form-data">
                  {% csrf_token %}

                <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div style="float: left; width: 50%">
                  <label for="title">Ad Title</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="title" style="float: right; width: 45%">
                    <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Type Here"           
    value='{{ form.title.value }}' required>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <br>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <div style="float: left; width: 50%">
                  <label for="city">City</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="city" style="float: right; width: 45%">
                    <select name="city"  value='{{ form.city.value }}'>
                      <option selected="selected" 
    value="islamabad">Islamabad</option>
                      <option value="karachi">Karachi</option>
                      <option value="lahore">Lahore</option>
                      <option value="peshawar">Peshawar</option>
                      <option value="quetta">Quetta</option>
                      <option value="multan">Multan</option>
                      <option value="faisalabad">Faisalabad</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <br>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <div style="float: left; width: 50%">
                  <label for="price">Price</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="price" style="float: right; width: 45%">
                    <input type="text" name="price" placeholder="Type Here" 
    value='{{ form.price.value }}' required>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <br>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <div style="float: left; width: 50%">
                  <label for="brand">Brand</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="brand" style="float: right; width: 45%">
                    <select name="brand" value='{{ form.brand.value }}'>
                      <option selected="selected" 
    value="honda">Honda</option>
                      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
                      <option value="bmw">BMW</option>
                      <option value="suzuki">Suzuki</option>
                      <option value="toyota">Toyota</option>
                      <option value="lexus">Lexus</option>
                      <option value="hyundai">Hyundai</option>
                      <option value="jeep">Jeep</option>
                      <option value="mazda">Mazda</option>
                      <option value="mitsubishi">Mitsubishi</option>
                      <option value="daewoo">Daewoo</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <br>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <div style="float: left; width: 50%">
                  <label for="modelyear">Model-Year</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modelyear" style="float: right; width: 45%">
                    <input type="text" name="modelyear" 
    placeholder="ie:1970-2018"  value='{{ form.modelyear.value }}' required>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <br>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <div style="float: left; width: 50%">
                  <label for="condition">Condition</label>
                  </div>
                <div class="condition" style="float: right; width: 45%">
                  <select name="condition"  value='{{ form.condition.value 
    }}'>
                    <option selected="selected" value="new">NEW</option>
                    <option value="used">USED</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
                </div>
                <br>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <div style="float: left; width: 50%">
                  <label for="mileage">Mileage</label>
                  </div>
                <div class=mileage style="float: right; width: 45%">
                    <input type="text" name="mileage" placeholder="ie:50000"  
    value='{{ form.mileage.value }}' required>
                </div>
              </div>
                </div>
                <br>


                <div class="form-group">
                  <div style="float: left; width: 50%">
                  <label for="details">Type details here</label>
                  </div>
                <div class="details" style="float: right; width: 45%">
                  <textarea name="details" rows="9" cols="45" value='{{ 
    form.details.value }}' required></textarea>
                </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>


                {{ formset.management_form }}
                  {% if formset %}
                    {% for form in formset %}
                      {% if form %}
                      <table class="display" cellspacing="1" width="100%">
                        <tr>
                          <td>{{ form }}</td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                      {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                  {% endif %}


                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update" class="btn 
    btn-info" id="post_btn">
            </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <script 
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"> 
   </script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" 


href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script 
   src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"> 
   </script>


    </body>
    </html>

    {% endblock %}
```

Comment: Apperently there is an instance where obj.id does not exist. Remove the update url from action. Load the page and check via the hidden input whether or not there is a valid / existing obj.id. BTW, do you get the error on the GET or POST request?

Comment: It will probably be the extra forms in your formset you are creating with an empty queryset.

Comment: You have shown your `index.html`, but none of the views you have shown use `index.html`. The error is probably coming from somewhere else. The full error message will include `NoReverseMatch at /foo/bar`. You can then find out the view that handles `/foo/bar` by looking at your URLs, then look at that view to see which template it renders. That's where the error is probably coming from.

Comment: @Alasdair my index.html is in blog urls and i have included my vehicles_app urls.py in blog urls...here's my blog urls.py looks like                   urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index,name='index'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^ind/$', views.ind, name='ind'),
    url(r'^vehicles_app/',include('vehicles_app.urls')),
    url(r'^logout/$',views.user_logout,name='logout')
]

Comment: @DisneylandSC i am using post method andi have checked it before,its getting the right obj.id but its not working at all where as my other buttons like details and delete are working fine

Comment: somebody help me,its my final project

Comment: You haven't responded to the points in my last comment. 1. What is the URL from the error message? 2. What view is handling that URL (add the view to the question if you haven't already)? 3. What template does that view use?

Comment: @Alasdair vehicles_app:update is the url from the error message, i have shown my update_post view above and template name is update_post.html in which all the updating fields are

Comment: `vehicles_app:update` is the name of the url pattern, it isn't the URL. The URL is something like `/5/update_post/`. So it sounds like the error is on `update_post.html`, but you still haven't shown that template in your question.

Comment: @Alasdair i didn't show that template because i thought the control is not even going to that template,because it's not getting the match for that...let me update with my update_post.html

Comment: I don't want the URL from `Reverse for 'update'`. I want the URL from `NoReverseMatch at /foo/bar` - that tells you where the URL is occurring.

Comment: Reverse for 'update' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<post_id>[0-9]+)/update_post/$']                   ......This is the error i am getting

Comment: @Alasdair thanks man for your help, i've edited and added my update_post.html template

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming from this url tag in your `update_post.html` template.

```
<form id="post_form" method="post" action="{% url 'vehicles_app:update_post' post_id %}"
```

You get the error `with arguments '('',)'` in the error message because you haven't included `post_id` in the template context. You can add it with:

```
return render(request, 'vehicles_app/update_post.html', {
    'form': form,
    'formset': formset, 
    'post_form': post_form,
    'post_id': post_id,
})
```

Remember to do this for GET and POST requests.

Comment: bro you have already helped me a lot but can i ask you about one more issue i'm currently having in my update view?

Comment: If you've got a diffent issue it's better to ask a new question. This page already has a lot of comments because it took a long time to figure out where the error was coming from and add that code to the question.

Comment: above in my update_post view i'm trying to update my post,my post is having two models, one model have multiple text fields and other one have formset factory image fields which lets the user to upload multiple pictures for his/her post...i am trying to update that post but my view is not working and it doesn't update the post,can you help me that how can i update the posts?

Comment: bro here's my other issue post on stackoverflow, can you plz help me in solving this issue?i'll be very thankful to you                       https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49604076/i-cant-update-my-post-using-modelformset-factory