# I can't update my post using modelformset factory

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views

i am using two models named Posts and PostPicture and posts model have multiple text fields whereas PostPicture model have one image field and one posts foreignkey field and i am using formset_factory on image field in views to let the user upload multiple images with the post, the problem is that whenever i try to update the post it updates the text fields of Posts model but it doesn't update the images i upload with it...there's something wrong with my update view and i can't figure out

Here's my views.py for update_post

```
    def update_post(request, post_id):
        ImageFormSet = modelformset_factory(PostPicture,
                              form=AddPictures, extra=5, min_num=1, 
                                        can_delete=True)
         post_form = get_object_or_404(Posts, pk=post_id)
         pics_form = PostPicture.objects.filter(post=post_id)
         if request.method == "POST":
            form = AddFile(request.POST, instance=post_form)
            formset = ImageFormSet(request.POST or None, queryset=pics_form)
            if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
                posting = form.save(commit=False)
                posting.user = request.user
                posting.save()

                for form in formset.cleaned_data:
                    image = form['image']
                    photo = PostPicture(post=posting, image=image)
                    photo.save()
                messages.success(request, 'Post updated Successfully!')
                return render(request, 'vehicles_app/addfile.html', {
                    'form': form,
                    'pics_form': pics_form,
                    'formset': formset,
                    'post_form': post_form,
                    'post_id': post_id,
                 })
            else:
                 messages.success(request, 'Post not updated Successfully!')
                 print(form.errors, formset.errors)
        else:
            form = AddFile(instance=post_form)
            formset = 
            ImageFormSet(queryset=PostPicture.objects.filter(post=post_id))
        return render(request, 'vehicles_app/update_post.html', {'form': 
                        form, 'formset': formset, 'pics_form': pics_form, 
                       'post_form':post_form,'post_id': post_id})
```

here's my update_post.html

```
                    <form id="post_form" method="post" action="{% url 
                                 'vehicles_app:update_post' post_id %}"
                  enctype="multipart/form-data">
                  {% csrf_token %}

                <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div style="float: left; width: 50%">
                  <label for="title">Ad Title</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="title" style="float: right; width: 45%">
                    <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Type Here" 
                           value='{{ form.initial.title }}' required>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <br>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <div style="float: left; width: 50%">
                  <label for="city">City</label>
                  </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <div style="float: left; width: 50%">
                  <label for="mileage">Mileage</label>
                  </div>
                <div class=mileage style="float: right; width: 45%">
                    <input type="text" name="mileage" placeholder="ie:50000"  
                               value='{{ form.initial.mileage }}' required>
                </div>
              </div>
                </div>
                <br>


                <div class="form-group">
                  <div style="float: left; width: 50%">
                  <label for="details">Type details here</label>
                  </div>
                <div class="details" style="float: right; width: 45%">
                  <textarea name="details" rows="9" cols="45" value='{{ 
                       form.initial.details }}' required></textarea>
                </div>
                </div>
                <br>


                {{ formset.management_form }}
                  {% if formset %}
                    {% for form in formset %}
                      {% if form %}
                      <table class="display" cellspacing="1" width="100%">
                        <tr>
                          <td>{{ form }}</td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                      {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                  {% endif %}


                  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update" 
                       class="btn btn-info" id="post_btn">
                  <input type=button class="btn btn-default" value="Cancel" 
                       onClick="javascript:history.go(-1);">
            </form>
```

Comment: There is too much code to debug here. To start with I would look at `pics_form = PostPicture.objects.filter(id=post_id)`. Shouldn't that be something like `.filter(post=post_id)`? I don't know why you have `queryset=PostPicture.objects.none()` in the `else:` block either.

Comment: @Alasdair i have made some edits and changed my code,i have edited queryset=PostPicture.objects.none() too but the issue is same,all other fields are updated but the formset pictures are not updating with them

Comment: You still have `PostPicture.objects.filter(id=post_id)`. It doesn't make sense to use a **post** id to filter the **post picture** id field.

Comment: @Alasdair my apologies, i had changed it in my views but forgot to change it here,and its still not working at all...i don't know why but everything looks fine and it should work

Comment: Look carefully at the code around `for form in formset.save(commit=False):`. Is that where you think the items should be saved? Add some printing or logging and make sure that every line does what you think it should do.

Comment: @Alasdair i have tried doing for form in formset.cleaned_data: instead of   for form in formset.save(commit=False):   but its still not working at all

Comment: "it's still not working at all" is not enough info. I can't debug this for you, there's simply too much code. Hope you figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Everyone on Stack Overflow is volunteering their time, there isn't anyone I can refer this to. I've tried to help you to narrow down the problem, but you're still saying things like "it's still not working at all". Unless you can identify the problem it's very difficult to help. Hope you figure out the problem.

Comment: @Alasdair i am using two models named Posts and PostPicture and posts model have multiple text fields whereas PostPicture model have one image field and one posts foreignkey field and i am using formset_factory on image field in views to let the user upload multiple images with the post, the problem is that whenever i try to update the post it updates the text fields of Posts model but it doesn't update the images i upload with it...there's something wrong with my update view and i can't figure out ...can you help now plz?i'm hopeless now